# Set saved attachment as featured image in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, wordpress-featured-image

In Wordpress i have a function that correctly save a new processed image as attachment.
What i need is to **set as featured image the attachmen**t after its saving.

Here the function:

```
 /* Save attachment */
        $siteurl = get_option( 'siteurl' );
        $file_info = getimagesize( $newFileName );
        //create an array of attachment data to insert into wp_posts table
        $tableParams = array(
            'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_date' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
            'post_date_gmt' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
            'post_title' => $_POST['title'] . '-' . $_POST['filter'],
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'ping_status' => 'closed',
            'post_name' => sanitize_title_with_dashes( str_replace( "_", "-", $_POST['name'] . '-' . $_POST['filter'] ) ),
            'post_modified' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
            'post_modified_gmt' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
            'post_parent' => 0,
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'guid' => $newFileName,
            'post_mime_type' => $file_info['mime'],
            'post_excerpt' => '',
            'post_content' => ''
        );
        // insert the database record
        $attachmentID = wp_insert_attachment( $tableParams, $newFileName, 0 );
        // generate metadata and thumbnails
        if ( $attachmentData = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachmentID, $newFileName ) ) {
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachmentID, $attachmentData );
        }
```

And i call it in javascript:

```
    ajaxcall = jQuery.post(ajaxparam.ajax_url,
    {
    action: 'new_image',
    image: imageData,
    format: format,
    title: imageTitle,
    name: imageName,
    filename: largeImage,
    filter: effect,
    nonce: ajaxparam.nonce,
    });

jQuery.when(ajaxcall).done(function(){
editor.insertContent(..............................);
});
```

So i tried to add to the function:

```
[......]
if ( $attachmentData = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachmentID, $newFileName ) ) {
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachmentID, $attachmentData );
}

global $post;
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachmentID);
```

or

```
add_post_meta($post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', $attachmentID);
```

or

```
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', $attachmentID );
```

in any case without success.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: `$add = update_post_meta(etc); var_dump($add);` See:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta#Return_Values

Comment: Unfortunately `var_dump($add)` causes function error.

Comment: Where is this code being used?

Comment: If i add `$add = update_post_meta($post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', $attachmentID); var_dump($add);` attachment saving fails.
If i remove `var_dump($add);` attachment saving works.

Comment: oh, I meant your main code... is that a `save_post`, or REST API, or XML-RPC, or...?

Comment: `add_action( 'wp_ajax_new_image', 'saveFilteredImage' );`

new_image is the action name for the ajax call.

Comment: ah, so `var_dump` really ain't gonna work. Then you should include the result of `update_post_` on the [Ajax response](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success) to check it on JS side